# Is it possible to use JavaScript to split PHP/SQL results in to seperate 'pages'?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am generating a HTML table using the below current code.

At the moment the results are limited to 10 rows.

I want to change this so that 100 rows are returned and the results are split in to 10 rows per 'page' using Bootstrap `<ul class="pagination">`.

Is it possible to do this with JavaScript so that I don't get links like `table.php?page=2` and so on?

Example code is appreciated as I've never touched JavaScript previously.

**PHP/SQL**:

```
  <?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  include('core/connection.php');

  if($conn){

  $stid = oci_parse($conn, "

    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
      SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
      FROM t1
      ORDER BY c1
    )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 10

  ");
  oci_execute($stid);

  echo "<table class='table table-hover '>
        <thread>
        <tr>
        <th>c1</th>
        <th>c2</th>
        <th>c3</th>
        <th>c4</th>
        </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>";

  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['0'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    unset($row);

  }

  echo "</tbody>
        </table>";

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);

  }
```

**Bootstrap**:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Take care, these links are recommended for SEO, a specific link to your content increase  the recognized amount of content.
But you can do it with AJAX or by loading more than 10 rows in a JS variable with json_encode().

Comment: When it comes to displaying data in a table, my goto place is always https://datatables.net. Is this something you could consider?

Comment: @WilliamGeorge Initially when I started out with what I'm building I wanted to use that, but couldn't get the server side (SQL) to work with it.